# Replace data in Excel workbook

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I repeat some processes every week in R, such that I generate the data in R, and then create graphs in Excel.  I currently use `write.xlsx` from the `openxlsx` package to write down the data into Excel. This overwrites the existing workbook, and I have to create the graphs again. Is there anyway to avoid overwriting the workbook and just replace the data in a pre-specified space so that I do not have to recreate the graphs? Ideally, this would also maintain the formatting of the existing workbook. Trying to avoid using VBA.

Comment: Have you tried `loadWorkbook` and then `writeData` and then `saveWorkbook`?